# Maximum of sideloaded apps on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, side-loading

How many applications can I sideload to Windows 10 Mobile? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As for the latest build, you can sideload n number of applications. **There's no limit.**

If you want to sideload/deploy apps to your phone, use 8.1sdk or xap deployer 2.0 or wppt on pc to do it. Also assure you install ipoverusb in pc sothat app deployment over usb is possible! 8.1sdk works with win 8 and 8.1pc but xap deployer 2.0 and wppt needs win 10 with 8.0sdk installed.

Comment: Sideloading a app can be done without any of those tools. Just copy the xap file and open file explorer and click on it.

Comment: we cant install xaps like that!

Comment: Checked the extension. I have done it with an appx file. Sorry for the confusion. However the point still holds valid. **You can sideload an app without any tools or PC.**

Comment: YEs, you're right, and unfortunately wrong too. some apps tends to show as installing but never shows up in applist (for eg;minecraft, interop tools, pogo UWP, app data manager,etc, i hav tried these, they failed to install, all were appx/appxbundles)

Comment: Interlop tools is an app like equalizer which shows in *Settings -> Extra*. But you are right regarding PoGo UWP. It cannot be deployed without a PC as it has two additional dependencies. But however apps can be deployed without any of those tools via a browser via device portal(http://127.0.0.1/). See this link for more info : http://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-pogo-uwp-pokemon-go-windows-10-mobile. **There is no need for an SDK or special tools to deploy apps.** at least incase of W mobile.

Comment: See the PoGo UWP wiki, https://github.com/ST-Apps/PoGo-UWP/wiki/Home-(EN). They are using the browser to deploy apps and not SDK. Using a SDK may be easy for developers. But many don't have an SDK installed. *Mentioning that an SDK or similar tools is required* can misinform the users and cause them to follow additional steps. Also any app which does not have a dependency can be installed from the File manager itself. **As a final note, any mordern app for Windows 10 mobile can be deployed without using any tools.**

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends on hardware capabilities of your phone and which apps you want to open. 6 or 8 is the largest number of apps you can open but i will say again ALL DEPEND OF YOUR PHONE

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Why does it depend on the phone?

Comment: I'm source, because some phone can't run 2 or more app with heavy hardware requirements, apps will be close.

Comment: I think by "sideloading" the OP means how many apps can be installed on the phone that are not being downloaded through the Windows Store.

Comment: you can't download app from other source, Windows Store is the official store, this isn't Andriod, that's the advantage for WP - Security

Comment: You certainly can sideload unsigned apps using the Windows SDK - just not those that have been ripped from the store.

Comment: It doesn't depend depend on phone. Previously, phones on 8.1 had ability to side-load 8, now with win 10 mobile, I think there's no limit because so far, i have deployed 16-20 apps on my 520